# Rails: Production environment works in Passenger but not on console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, bundler, production

We have an application running with Rails 3.0.14 on a server which hosts both staging and production environments (using Debian Linux and Apache 2). Deployment is done using Bundler and Capistrano with the multistage extension. Both environments work fine from Apache Passenger and the production environment is actively used.

However, for some reason since the last deployment our cron scripts stopped working because for some reason the console does not like our production environment any more. No matter what `rake` or `rails` command we use, we always get

```
$ rails c
script/rails:6:in `require': no such file to load -- rails/commands (LoadError)
    script/rails:6
```

`bundle install` just runs through all gems and says "everything is fine". But compared to the staging environment, I *know* that some gems are missing in the shared bundle directory (from comparison with the staging environment which works).

How do I force Bundler to *reinstall* all required gems, even if it assumes everything is fine? It does not seem to have a '--force' switch.

Thanks!

Comment: try `bundle rails console staging`

Comment: What happens when you run: RAILS_ENV=production rails c

Comment: Also you say the gems differ between production and development.  That would be the case if you have a group :development in your Gemfile, your not relying on any gems in that block in production are you?

Comment: I have the same gem set in production and staging, and changing environment variables unfortunately did not help, neither did "bundle". But I fixed it anyway, see below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, but I still don't know how this happened.

It seems the 'railties' gem in the production tree was marked as installed, but the directory it was installed under was half empty (compared to the staging tree). Bundler kept insisting it was installed fine, but half the library files were missing and since 'railties' provides command line and script support, this was exactly what wasn't there.

I still don't understand how Bundler can semi-install a gem this way, but at least I was able to fix the situation by copying the missing files from the staging system.

Thank you for all comments, they helped me look in the right direction.

Comment: File a bug with bundler?  https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/1-2-stable/ISSUES.md